# keyboard shortcut for assignment pipe (%<>%) in RStudio?

Tags: rstudio

Does the assignment pipe %<>% from `magrittr` package have a keyboard shortcut in RStudio?

If not, how can I add it?

Comment: By going to Tools -> Modify shortcuts...

Comment: There isn't a preexisting shortcut for it in Rstudo

Answer (score 2):

Install the [extrainserts](https://konradzdeb.github.io/extraInserts/) package, which creates several Rstudio AddIns.
One of them inserts the `%<>%` operator and automatically surrounds it by single spaces.

Then you can search for `Insert %<>%` within the RStudio Keyboard Shortcuts Menu (access via e.g. `Tools` -> `Modify Keyboard Shortcuts`) and assign it to your preferred keybinding.